# how to find the latest image uploader between followers

Tags: mysql

Table image's variables are `[ID],[IMAGE_NAME][TIME]`

Table follow's variables are `[ID], [FLOOWER_ID]`

If me or a follower upload image, the information is saved in image table in this situation. I want to know,  how to find  the latest image uploader between followers.

Comment: just as FYI, tables don't have variables but columns or attributes. So instead of: "Table follow's variables are [ID], [FLOOWER_ID]" you can say: "Table follow's columns/attributes are [ID], [FLOOWER_ID]". Please feel free to edit and improve post.

Answer (score 0):

select follow_b, max(time) as maxtime from image inner join follow on image.id=follow.follow_b  group by follow_b order by maxtime desc ;

Comment: follow_b = floower_id

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tbl_image order by time desc limit 1
```

here you can grab the first id of image

then use the id to get the follower id , let say xx

```
select * from tbl_follow where id = xx
```